# How do I mention the quality of my school without bragging

Tags: resume, applications

I am currently studying at a US university that is among the top school for the field I'm in (CS). However, the university itself is not well known outside the US, and certainly not as being on par with or better than the more well known universities (Harvard, Princeton, etc.).

I normally wouldn't mind this, but I am currently in the process of applying for jobs back home in Europe and I fear that my application would not get the same attention as those coming from more well-known schools. So my question is:

How do I mention that I obtained my degree from a top school in my field without it sounding braggy?

This would be good to know in terms of a cover letter and in an interview setting.

Comment: @MartinYork Sadly, that depends on the country/culture. There are a lot of cultures where school >> ability

Comment: Even if your university isn't well known, if the program is top ranked, anyone really evaluating your resume likely already knows it.  I have no idea about Canadian universities but I know the University of Waterloo because I'm in the CS field.  I have no idea what the top schools for art restoration are but I'm pretty sure someone interviewing at the Museum of Modern Art does.  The person on the street knows Harvard, the person across the table from you likely knows your school if it is generally recognized as a top school in the field.

Comment: @Mars that’s the Peter Principle at work...

Comment: @SolarMike How so? Are you implying the recruiter is inadequate so they simply hire from the best school? Either way, I believe the premise is "You're still a snot nosed brat and we're gonna have to train anyone who enters, so at least hire the snot nosed brat who managed to study their way into a decent university". I'm not saying the premise is correct, but I can at least follow the logic!

Comment: @Mars it was your clear assumption of "school >> ability" I was referring to  - perhaps you should be able to follow that...

Comment: @SolarMike Sorry, I wasn't implying that you couldn't follow the logic. I meant that I didn't agree with what I was saying, but that doesn't change the fact that it's how some cultures rationalize it and I understand that. As the for Peter principle part, I still don't follow how it's related--as I understand Peter Principle is that you rise beyond your ability and stay there, which seems very unrelated to choosing Mr. Harvard over Mr. Internship

Comment: This question basically distills down to, "How do I brag about my school without bragging about my school?"  Which is funny, because the answer is, "You *should* brag about your school in an interview"  :-)

Comment: If your university is really in the top few in the US in CS, people hiring in CS positions will likely have heard of it.

Comment: On a resume, it's not bragging, it's marketing

Comment: for the interview itself, try to "feel" the niterviewer before bragging. Someone not knowing well the dmoain and feeling unsure might like the reference, while a veteran of the domain will be more interestd by your actual skills.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

> How do I mention that I obtained my degree from a top school in my
>   field without it sounding braggy?

You use your cover letter. In it, you should brag.

Something along the lines of "I graduated summa cum laude from Tiptop University - one of the 7 top Computer Science schools in the U.S." is perfectly appropriate.

Unless your interviewer specifically asks about your schooling or about your university, there's no need to bring it up during the interview itself. Once you reach that stage, they have already read your cover letter. And if they weren't familiar with your school already and cared, they Googled it already.

Comment: Would one somewhere mention the institution who did the ranking, or the year of ranking?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would you mention this in an interview setting as well?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Regarding Arsak's question, if you're going to rely on the employers google search, you might want to suggest doing your own google searches first. If "my school CS dept ranking" turns up wildly different results...

Comment: A great answer. For me whenever I've interviewed people, at that point I'm more interested in what they've gained from their experience and education than just where they got it.

Comment: Even if the recruiter or interviewer has googled your university, if he asks to describe your schooling in person would it be faux pas to state that it is a leading university? Or is that strictly confined to the cover letter.

Comment: @MaartenW. Personally I would refrain, I can see an interviewer taking it like you're bragging and be annoyed. You should instead focus on what your learned, whether it's pure theory, practice, or transversal skills, how autonomous or guided it was, how many projects and group projects you completed, etc.

Comment: Point of reference: I've always researched universities extensively and basically ignored what the candidate had to say about them. All universities have some metric where they come out on top.

Comment: "one of the 7 top schools" sounds weird. I would read that as "precisely 7th best"

Comment: I would gently push the CV to the trash if someone presented it to me like that. Your school being one of the best means bollocks in CS - I got _a few_ people from Harvard that couldn't type two lines of code without fumbling something up. Computer Science academic courses are notoriously weak in forming competent programmers.

Comment: @T.Sar But that's all the OP's got for experience. Linus Torvalds wouldn't put that down, but he's not Linus Torvalds. If a company is expecting a master programmer with 30 years experience in an entry-level job with a entry-level salary, I wouldn't want to work there either.

Comment: @user71659 That's why internships are so important on IT. I would be happier to hire a guy from an unknown college but with 1-year of internships and a couple personal projects under his belt than I would be hiring a Harvard graduate that never saw real-life code.

Comment: @user71659 More so, your college ranking is _not_ your experience. A published paper, a presentation on a seminar, a tool made just got fun - those are valid experience. "My college ranks 7th" isn't.

Comment: @T.Sar You speak like someone who didn't attend a top 7 college:) Hiring a new-grad is a crap shoot. Internships seldom provide enough experience to truly evaluate a person's skills; let alone potential. We don't hire new-grads for what they can do NOW, we hire based on what we think they will be capable of doing 2 years and more from now. All other factors being equal, the quality of the school combined with GPA is an extremely strong indicator of potential. It's not always an accurate heuristic but it increases the odds. You don't do well at a top school without being very smart.

Comment: @Dunk I speak as someone who had four years of experience in real-life, non-internship roles by the time I finished college and knows how useless a diploma is when compared to actual, battle-tested skills in the area. Don't get me wrong - it is nice and all if you got that fancy Harvard, Stanford or Yale diploma, but they mean absolutely nothing if show up to the interview and fail at a simple foobar exercise - something that happens WAY more often than it should.

Comment: @T.Sar I guess useless is a relative term. If a company needs someone who can not only program but also quickly come up to speed in different problem domains then that fancy diploma becomes a lot more attractive as that broad education turns out to be anything but useless. How many Harvard, Stanford or Yale graduates have you had the pleasure of giving a foobar test to? Even if a new grad fails the foobar test; it doesn't say anything about their potential. Many new grads are scared to death when they show up for interviews.

Comment: Five from Harvard. All but one failed the test. Had way better luck with MIT - never got a bad candidate from there. And I completely disagree - a foobar is absolute minimum if you want to have any sort of shot to a programming job. It is a super easy task.

Comment: @Dunk [I refer you to this link](https://blog.codinghorror.com/why-cant-programmers-program/):

Comment: @Dunk (btw, I've been calling it a foobar but it is actually called "fizzbuzz". An old senior of mine called the test that way and it stuck with me)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92636/discussion-on-answer-by-joe-strazzere-how-do-i-mention-the-quality-of-my-school).

Answer (score 9):

I would flip the problem around - "Show don't tell". Use your CV to demonstrate the quality of the syllabus and discuss any relevant or impressive courseworks. Ultimately you are being hired, not your school.

Comment: Don't be so sure of that, of course professionaly we should consider than recruitment should evaluate fully candidates but reality is that the name of your school can make a lot of difference. Even more in domain where interview aren't good at evaluating the skills of the people.

Comment: I interview and make decisions on hires frequently. I barely glance at an applicant's school. I do spend a lot of time looking for experience, thought.

Answer (score 3):

Job interviews are the places you should be bragging. But I use numbers instead of statements to sound more polite.

So, it may sound like bragging when you say "Maybe you never heard of it's name, but it is an awesome school that people says 'wow' when they hear where you are graduated from".

But you are free to state this as "This school comes 5th in Computer Science, right after Harvard."

Comment: Depending on culture, this may be your case (though I don't think so in Germany (so your profile says)). It's definitely the think to do for cover letters with the resume, but would not recommend this for the actual interviews. Would drop a hint about it if the interviewer mentions the place of study, but still would not go full-on brag ;-) But, people and situations differ, so... go for it ?

Comment: It depends a lot of the field. If you're in sales, bragging is a needed skill. If you're in CS, full of shy and very territorial people, bragging would be viewed very negatively.

Answer (score 3):

On my resume (CV) I give a phrase about each company to set the basic tone of what industry or purpose it addressed was.  I see no reason you couldn't do so about your school:

> **ABC University** Anytown, USA
>   *US Top 10 Computer Science Dept.*